# Ansible fails to import tasks and vars due to not finding the files

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to import the task located at the given directory on my localhost, import from there task and import the values from it to use in my new ansible:

Here is my ansible-playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true 
  tasks:
    - name: Get root password variable
      include_vars:
      file: './roles/playbook_i_am_importing/vars/main.yml'
    - name: Change password
      import_tasks: ./playbook_i_am_importing/tasks/main.yml
      tags: change_pass`
```

Here is how my ./roles/playbook_i_am_importing/vars/main.yml look like:

```yaml
password: censored
ansible_user: test_user_for_ansible
```

Here is how my ./playbook_i_am_importing/tasks/main.yml look like:

```yaml
---
    - name: Change password
      become: true
      user:
        name: tester123
        password: "{{ password }}"
      tags:
        - change_pass
```

Every file that is I am trying to import located on my localhost, where I execute the playbook.

I have tried playing around values, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Given the role

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
└── importing
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    └── vars
        └── main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/importing/tasks/main.yml 
- name: Change password
  debug:
    msg: |
      name: tester123
      password: {{ password }}
  tags: change_pass
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/importing/vars/main.yml 
password: censored
ansible_user: test_user_for_ansible
```

**roles**

Run the role. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb-roles.yml
- hosts: all

  roles:

    - importing
```

gives (limited to single node test_11)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb-roles.yml -l test_11

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [importing : Change password] ************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    name: tester123
    password: censored

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**tasks**

Use the module [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html) if you want to control the execution. For example, the below play gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat pb-tasks.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - import_role:
        name: importing
        tasks_from: main.yml
        vars_from: main.yml
```